# How to join two tables using partition (or something else)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, google-bigquery

I have two tables:

- table A with sales products (test1, test2) with every day information
- table B with history of category changes of these products (product can change category once a year or every day, it depends on products)

And I want to have sales with current categories of products to this day (if category changed today i want to see it to this day and later, before next change)

Please help without many subqueries (tables are heavy)

```
    TABLE A >>
        uid  name  date
        1   test1  2019-09-01
        2   test1  2019-09-02
        3   test1  2019-09-03
        4   test2  2019-09-01
        5   test2  2019-09-02
        6   test2  2019-09-03

    TABLE B >>
    uid  name  date_change  category
    1   test1  2019-08-30  cat1
    2   test1  2019-09-02  cat2
    4   test1  2019-09-04  cat3
    5   test2  2019-09-01  cat4
    6   test2  2019-09-03  cat5

    TABLE Result >>
    uid  name  date       date_change  category
    1   test1  2019-09-01  2019-08-30  cat1
    2   test1  2019-09-02  2019-09-02  cat2
    3   test1  2019-09-03  2019-09-02  cat2
    4   test2  2019-09-01  2019-09-01  cat4
    5   test2  2019-09-02  2019-09-01  cat4
    6   test2  2019-09-03  2019-09-03  cat5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT a.name, `date`, date_change, category
FROM `project.dataset.tableA` a
LEFT JOIN(
  SELECT name, date_change, category, 
    DATE_SUB(LEAD(date_change, 1, DATE '2100-01-01') OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY date_change), INTERVAL 1 DAY) last_day
  FROM `project.dataset.tableB` 
) b
ON a.name = b.name 
AND a.date BETWEEN b.date_change AND b.last_day
-- ORDER BY name, date_change
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row name    date        date_change category     
1   test1   2019-09-01  2019-08-30  cat1     
2   test1   2019-09-02  2019-09-02  cat2     
3   test1   2019-09-03  2019-09-02  cat2     
4   test2   2019-09-01  2019-09-01  cat4     
5   test2   2019-09-02  2019-09-01  cat4     
6   test2   2019-09-03  2019-09-03  cat5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a correlated subquery to retrieve the latest `cat` from `b` prior to the `date` of `a`:

```
select 
    a.*,
    (
        select cat 
        from b 
        where b.name = a.name and b.date_changed <= a.date 
        order by b.date_changed desc 
        limit 1
    ) cat
from a
```

Comment: Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN.